# Is there a gem that provides support to detect changes to native ruby type instances?

Tags: ruby, class, oop, inheritance

Although I agree that extending native types and objects is a bad practice, inheriting from them should not be.

In a supposedly supporting gem (that I could not find), the way that the native types were to be used would be as follows:

```
require 'cool-unkown-light-gem'

class MyTypedArray < CoolArray # would love to directly < Array
  def initialize(*args)
    super(*args)
    # some inits for DataArray
    @caches_init = false
  end

  def name?(name)
    init_caches unless !@caches_init
    !!@cache_by_name[name]
  end

  def element(name)
    init_caches unless !@caches_init
    @cache_by_name[name]
  end

  private

  # overrides the CoolArray method:
  # CoolArray methods that modify self will call this method
  def on_change
    @caches_init = false
    super
  end

  def init_caches
    return @cache_by_name if @caches_init
    @caches_init = true
    @cache_by_name = self.map do |elem|
      [elem.unique_name, elem]
    end.to_h
  end
end
```

Any method of the parent class not overridden by the child class that modifies self would call, let's say (in this case), the `on_change` function. Which would allow to do not have to re-define every single one of those methods to avoid losing track on changes.

Let's say the `MyTypedArray` would array `Foo` objects:

```
class Foo
  attr_reader :unique_name
  def initialize(name)
    @unique_name = name
  end
end
```

a short example of the expected behaviour of its usage:

```
my_array = MyTypedArray.new
my_array.push( Foo.new("bar") ).push( Foo.new("baz") )

my_array.element("bar").unique_name
# => "bar"

my_array.shift # a method that removes the first element from self
my_array.element("bar").unique_name
# => undefined method `unique_name' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

my_array.name?("bar")
# => false
```

I understand that we should search for immutable classes, yet those native types support changes on the same object and we want a proper way to do an inheritance that is as brief and easy as possible.

Any thoughts, approaches, or recommendations are more than welcome, of course. I do not think I am the only one that have thought on this.

The reason why I am searching for a maintained gem is because different ruby versions may offer different supported methods or options for native types / classes.

**[Edit]**

The aim of the above is to figure out a pattern that works. I could just follow the rules and suggestions of other posts, yet would not get things work the way I am intended and when I see it proper (a coding language is made by and for humans, and not humans made for coding languages). I know everyone is proud of their achievements in learning, developing and making things shaped in a pattern that is well known in the community.

The target of the above is because all the `methods` of `Array` are more than welcome. I do not care if in the version 20 of Ruby they remove some methods of Array. By then my application will be obsolete or someone will achieve the same result in far less code.

**Why `Array`**?

Because the order matters.

**Why an internal `Hash`**?

Because for the usage I want to make of it, in overall, the cost of building the hash compensates the optimization it offers.

**Why not just `include Enumerable`**?

Because we just reduce the number of methods that change the object, but we do not actually have a pattern that allows to change `@caches_init` to `false`, so the `Hash` is rebuilt on next usage (so same problem as with `Array`)

**Why not just whitelist and include target `Array` methods**?

Because that does not get me where I want to be. What if I want anyone to still use `pop`, or `shift` but I do not want to redefine them, or even having to bother to manage my mixins and constantly having to use `responds_to?`? (perhaps that exercise is good to improve your skills in coding and read code from other people, but that is not what it should be)

**Where I want to be**?

I want to be in a position that I can re-use / inherit any, I repeat, any class (no matter if it is native or not). That is basic for an OOP language. And if we are not talking about an OOP language (but just some sugar at the top of it to make it appear as OOP), then let's keep ourselves open to analyse patterns that should work well (no matter if they are odd - for me is more odd that there are no intermediate levels; which is symptom of many conventional patterns, which in turn is symptom of poor support for certain features that are more widely required than what is accepted).

**Why should a gem offer the above**?

Well, let's humble it. The above is a very simple case (and even though not covered). You may gain in flexibility at some point by using what some people want to call *the Ruby way*. But at a cost when you move to bigger architectures. What if I want to create intermediate classes to inherit from? Enriched native classes that boost simple code, yet keeping it aligned with the language. It is easier to say *this is not the Ruby way* than trying to make the language closer to something that escalates well from the bottom.

I am not surprised that Rails and Ruby are almost "indistinctly" used by many. Because at some point, without some Rails support, what you have with Ruby is a lot of trouble. As, consequently, I am not surprised that Rails is so maintained.

Why should I redefine a `pop`, or a `last`, or `first` methods? For what? They are already implemented.
Why should I whitelist methods and create mixins? is that a object or method oriented programming?

Anyway... I do not expect anyone to share my view on this. I do see other patterns, and I will keep allowing my mind to find them. If anyone is open enough, please, feel free to share. Someone may criticize the approach and be right, but if you got there is because it worked.

Comment: Your design patterns do not really adhere to what would be considered "normal" in Ruby. From what I can gather, you are trying to implement an observer pattern, which the standard library already has a helper module for. [Observable](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/observer/rdoc/Observable.html)

Comment: I also wouldn't typically consider it good practice to inherit from `Array`. Again, ruby's core library provides a (typically) far better approach for constructing classes with traversal and searching methods: You include the [`Enumerable`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html) module in your class.

Comment: @TomLord all good... this is not a criticism to other's point of view. It is a question. And your answer is include the Enumerable module; which still has methods that modify self (i.e. `drop`). I cannot link you answer to my question, although I would appreciate any feedback to know what I have asked wrong so the question would not be understood.

Comment: @ForeverZer0 could you please specify what a normal pattern would be? I thank you for your feedback on Observable (looks interesting). However, I do not see it simpler or better than the approach I drawn above (normal or not)

Comment: Your "short example" doesn't make sense. `my_array` is an object in the first line in the example, yet it is treated as a method in `my_array("bar")`.

Comment: @rellampec I wasn't directly answering your question;  I was providing a general comment on the approach. (Hence I made it a comment, not an answer.) As Masa says, I don't really know how to answer your question because your example doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @MasaSakano thanks... hope now, at least the use of the method, makes sense (edited).

Comment: You may wish to clarify the end result behavior that is actually required, as this seems like it could possibly be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). Even with implementing it manually, this is not going to ever be a robust solution. Soon as someone extends the class or one of its ancestors, uses a mix-in, alias, duck-type, etc, all of this is going to break, and it is beyond what you could ever anticipate, as the possibilities are endless.

Comment: It appears you may be trying to implement design patterns you may know or understand from another language (one that is statically-typed), but don't really fit well into Ruby.

Comment: @ForeverZer0 perhaps I would love to know what really fits well in Ruby ;)

Comment: That's why I thought to ask to maybe elaborate on what you really need, not how to solve this specific question, as you will likely get better answers. For example, explain the purpose of the `MyTypedArray` and `CoolArray`. The change to `self` is done internally to the C structure the object is backed by. There is no shortcut, in Ruby or C that detects when the a pointer/value within the struct is re-assigned. Kinda why I thought it may be XY Problem. That is an oddly specific behavior that is typically not ever required, and one that likely has existing alternatives.

Comment: @ForeverZer0 thanks again... extended the question... please see edit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182654/discussion-between-rellampec-and-foreverzer0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question as it is written, **no**, there is no gem for this. This is not a possibility of the language, either in pure Ruby or in C which is used internally.

There is no mechanism in detect when `self` is changed, nor any way to detect if a method is pure (does not change self) or impure (does change self). It seems you want a way to  "automatically" be able to know when a method is one or the other, and that, to put simply,  is just not possible, nor is it in any language that I am aware of.

Internally (using your example) an `Array` is backed by a `RArray` structure in C. A struct is simple storage space: a way to look at an arbitrary block of memory. C does not care how you choose to look at memory, I could just as easily cast the pointer of this struct and say it is a now a pointer to an array of integers and change it that way, it will happily manipulate the memory as I tell it to, and there is nothing that can detect that I did so. Now add in the fact that anyone, any script, or any gem can do this and you have no control over it, and it just shows that this solution is fundamentally and objectively flawed.

This is why most (all?) languages that need to be notified when an object is changed use an observer pattern. You create a function that "notifies" when something changes, and you invoke that function manually when needed. If someone decides to subclass your class, they need only continue the pattern to raise that function if it changes the object state.

**There is no such thing as an automatic way of doing this.** As already explained, this is an "opt-in" or "whitelist" solution. If you want to subclass an existing object instead of using your own from scratch, then you need to modify its behavior accordingly.

That said, adding the functionality is not as daunting as you may think if you use some clever aliasing and meta-programming with `module_eval`, `class_eval` or the like.

```
# This is 100% untested and not even checked for syntax, just rough idea

def on_changed
  # Do whatever you need here when object is changed
end

# Unpure methods like []=, <<, push, map!, etc, etc
unpure_methods.each do |name|
  class_eval <<-EOS
    alias #{name}_orig #{name}
    def #{name}(*args, &block)
      #{name}_orig(*args, &block)
      on_changed
    end
  EOS
end
```

Comment: thanks, this really helpers. I think that this pattern can somehow be used with the Observable you mentioned, or at least, contextualize it better... will have a closer look at it.